# UITabbar still active under another UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBar on the screen and a View with some buttons on it. When a button is clicked, I create a ViewController (with a view from a nib) and add it to the keywindow of the application. I put this view offscreen and start an animation to make this new view slides from the bottom of the screen, and cover the tabBar. On this new view there is a UIPicker and 2 buttons (select / cancel). When one of this buttons is clicked, the PickerView slide off the screen and his controller is dealloc.

This works fine except for one thing : if I click on the zone where the tabBar is located and hidden by my new view, the tabBar get the click event !

How can I make the tabBar non responsive ? (Remember that I don't push the new view) Or maybe it isn't the right way to do this ?

*EDIT & ANSWER : The problem came from the fact that I did a mistake in the height setting. I typed 160 instead of 260. 
[myPickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 260)];
The last 100 px, even if displayed, where "transparent" to event and get transfered to the TabBar who stands in that zone (even if it was hidden).*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but why don't you try

```
yourTabbar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

when the view is visible. Make sure you set

```
yourTabbar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

when view is dismissed.

Comment: I guess that when you talked about yourTabbar, you talk about the yourTabbarView, isn't it ? Is there a path to get to the TabBarController within one of his views ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use method named in your application:

```
tabbar1.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```